# Ruby on Rails allowing sessions between ports locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise, localhost

Basically I am developing an API in rails with RocketPants and Devise and I'm creating a client with AngularJS. since they are in folders maintained by seperate people I run the rails api on `localhost:3000` and the client on `localhost:8000` and in the live environment they will be on subdomains of the same top level domain.  `api.example.com` `app.example.com`.

I have allowed for cross domain requests using Rack Cors and this seems to work fine, I can query for things and log in by sending my credentials to the API (I have also checked if this works by returning the logged in user's id).

However the client does not seem to hang on to the session, after I log in and get back confirmation that I logged in successfully and I make another request it says the `current_user` is Nil.

I have allowed for subdomains in rails I think by using the following in `session_store.rb`

```
AppName::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_app-name_session', domain: :all
```

I cannot test this however.

Is there a good way to share sessions between ports locally? Or is there a good way to emulate subdomains for local testing between 2 projects (1 rails, 1 standalone)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using [Pow](http://pow.cx) to serve your apps in development?

You could then run them on the subdomains, just like you do in production.

Comment: looks promising, I'll check it out now

Comment: Works very well, the cookie session problem is still not solved, but POW gives a good way to test my code locally. thanks!

Comment: Glad that worked. For the cookie session, I would try explicitly defining your domains there.

    AppName::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_app-name_session', domain: '*.apphost.dev'